# Summarizing using dplyr with a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, group-by, dplyr, summarize

I would like to summarise each of my independant variables (columns) with my target variable using `dplyr` over a for loop. This is my main dataframe:

```
  contract_ID    Asurion         Variable_1     Variable_2  Variable_3
         1          Y                a               c          f
         2          Y                a               d          g
         3          N                b               c          g
         4          N                a               d          f
         5          Y                b               c          f
         6          Y                a               d          f
```

After the group by I get

```
a1 <- a %>% 
  group_by(Asurion,BhvrBnk_Donates_to_Env_Causes) %>%       
  summarise(counT=n_distinct(CONTRACT_ID)) %>%                                        
  mutate(perc=paste0(round(counT/sum(counT)*100,2),"%"))

 Asurion Variable_1 CounT   perc
    Y         a        3     75%
    Y         b        1     25%
    N         a        1     50%
    N         b        1     50%
```

I would like to have this summairsation for each of my variable present in my dataframe and I would like to do this using a for loop. How do i get to my desired result

This is what I have tried using but it doesnt seem to work. it is for a school project and I need to use a for loop for this. Please help me out here

```
categorical <- colnames(a)###where categroical is the names of all columns in a  
###I would like to have a for loop for every column in a and summarise in the following way. I would like to store each of the summarisations in a separate dataframe 

for (i in categorical) {
  a[[i]] <- a %>% 
     group_by(Asurion,get(i)) %>% 
    summarise(counT=n_distinct(CONTRACT_ID)) %>% 
    mutate(perc=paste0(round(counT/sum(counT)*100,2),"%"))
  }
```

Comment: Based on your comments, could you also include intended output? This seems like an xy problem where people may have had different approaches had you indicated your final output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not really need `for loop` to get what you wanted.

```
df<-data.frame(contract_ID = 1:6, 
               Asurion = c("Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y"), 
               Variable_1 = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b","a"), 
               Variable_2 = c("c", "d", "c", "d", "c", "d"), 
               Variable_3 = c("f", "g", "g", "f", "f", "f"))

pct <- function(x) {
  df %>% 
  group_by(Asurion, {{x}}) %>% 
  summarise(counT=n_distinct(contract_ID)) %>% 
  mutate(perc = paste0(round(counT/sum(counT)*100,2),"%"))
}

pct(Variable_1)
pct(Variable_2)
pct(Variable_3)
```

If you do have many variables, you could use something like `for loop` or `apply` to iterate the last bit. 
Here is one option:

```
categorical<- df[3:5]
a <- list()
j = 1
for (i in categorical) {
  a[[j]] <- df %>% 
    group_by(Asurion, {{i}}) %>% 
    summarise(counT=n_distinct(contract_ID)) %>% 
    mutate(perc = paste0(round(counT/sum(counT)*100,2),"%"))
  j = j + 1
}
a
```

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Asurion [2]
  Asurion `<fct>` counT perc 
  <fct>   <fct>   <int> <chr>
1 N       a           1 50%  
2 N       b           1 50%  
3 Y       a           3 75%  
4 Y       b           1 25%  

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Asurion [2]
  Asurion `<fct>` counT perc 
  <fct>   <fct>   <int> <chr>
1 N       c           1 50%  
2 N       d           1 50%  
3 Y       c           2 50%  
4 Y       d           2 50%  

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Asurion [2]
  Asurion `<fct>` counT perc 
  <fct>   <fct>   <int> <chr>
1 N       f           1 50%  
2 N       g           1 50%  
3 Y       f           3 75%  
4 Y       g           1 25%
```

**EDIT**
Add variable names as new variable values in response to your question to identify `group_by` variables.

```
categorical<- df[3:5]
vnames <- colnames(categorical)
a <- list()
j = 1
for (i in categorical) {
  a[[j]] <- df %>% 
    group_by(Asurion, {{i}}) %>% 
    summarise(counT=n_distinct(contract_ID)) %>% 
    mutate(perc = paste0(round(counT/sum(counT)*100,2),"%"))
    a[[j]]$vnames = vnames[j]
  j = j + 1
}
a
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was new to writing loops and hence wanted to understand if for can be used here. Following up on your question, I do have about 50 variables in the dataset. I tried using: 
    ```categorical <-colnames(a) ```
```categorical <- categorical[3:42]``` 
```for (i in categorical) { a[[i]]<- pct([i]) } ```
But doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Thanks for this, this is exactly what I was looking for. But the problem here is since all of the them are getting stored in a list and when I combine them in to a dataframe I am not able to distinguish which variable gave me what results. Is there a way to solve this?
I was trying this ```b <- list()
j = 1

for (i in categorical) {
  b[[j]] <- a %>% 
    group_by(Asurion, {{i}}) %>% 
    summarise(counT=n_distinct(CONTRACT_ID)) %>% 
    mutate(perc = paste0(round(counT/sum(counT)*100,2),"%"),v=colnames(i))
  j = j + 1
}
```

Comment: I don't have a quick answer yet. I am still learning `{{` myself. I think the ideal way to do this is that `{{` passes that the real variable names rather than "`<fct>`"

Comment: I have added my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Base R Solution:

```
 df2 <- data.frame(

  reshape(df,

          direction = "long",

          varying = names(df)[!(names(df) %in% c("contract_ID", "Asurion"))],

          v.names = "Val",

          timevar = "Variable",

          times = names(df)[!(names(df) %in% c("contract_ID", "Asurion"))]

  ),

  row.names = NULL,

  stringsAsFactors = F

)

# Count the unique contract ids within the specified group: 

df2$CounT <- as.numeric(ave(df2$contract_ID,

                            paste(df2$Asurion, df2$Variable, df2$Val, sep = "_"),

                            FUN = function(x){length(unique(x))}))

# Create the percentage of total counts: 

df2$perc <- paste0(round((df2$CounT/as.numeric(ave(df2$Variable, 

                                                   paste(df2$Variable, df2$Val, sep = "_"),

                                                   FUN = length))) * 100,2),"%")

# Allocate some memory for list of dataframes: 

df_list <- vector("list", length(unique(df2$Variable)))

# Store the summary dataframes in the list: 

df_list <- lapply(split(df2, df2$Variable),

                  function(x){x <- unique(x[,c(!(names(x) %in% c("id", "contract_ID")))])})

# Push the dataframes from the list into the global environment: 

list2env(df_list, .GlobalEnv)
```

Tidyverse Solution:

```
require(tidyverse)

# Allocate some memory for list of dataframes: 

df_list <- vector("list", length(unique(names(df)[grepl("Variable_", names(df))])))

# Tidyverse summary: 

df_list <- 

  df %>% 

  gather(Variable, Value, -contract_ID, -Asurion) %>% 

  group_by(Asurion, Variable, Value) %>% 

  mutate(CounT = length(unique(contract_ID))) %>%

  ungroup() %>% 

  group_by(Variable, Value) %>% 

  mutate(perc = paste0(round((CounT/n()) * 100, 2), "%")) %>% 

  ungroup() %>% 

  select(-contract_ID) %>% 

  distinct() %>% 

  split(., .$Variable)

# Push the dataframes from the list into the global environment: 

list2env(df_list, .GlobalEnv)
```

Data:

```
structure(list(contract_ID = 1:6, Asurion = c("Y", "Y", "N", 
"N", "Y", "Y"), Variable_1 = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"), 
    Variable_2 = c("c", "d", "c", "d", "c", "d"), Variable_3 = c("f", 
    "g", "g", "f", "f", "f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: @Cole dropped id vector from splitting and distinct function, result should be correct. Your solutions are superbly eloquent btw.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) and [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) way that produces a list of results per your question:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

DF%>%
  add_count(Asurion, name = 'all_n')%>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Variable'))%>%
  group_by(Asurion, name, value)%>%
  summarize(CounT = n(), 
            perc = n() / first(all_n))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  group_split(name, keep = F)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Asurion value CounT  perc
  <fct>   <fct> <int> <dbl>
1 N       a         1  0.5 
2 N       b         1  0.5 
3 Y       a         3  0.75
4 Y       b         1  0.25

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Asurion value CounT  perc
  <fct>   <fct> <int> <dbl>
1 N       c         1   0.5
2 N       d         1   0.5
3 Y       c         2   0.5
4 Y       d         2   0.5

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Asurion value CounT  perc
  <fct>   <fct> <int> <dbl>
1 N       f         1  0.5 
2 N       g         1  0.5 
3 Y       f         3  0.75
4 Y       g         1  0.25
```

And a base solution as well that better matches the intended output:

```
## base
lapply(grep('Variable', names(DF), value = T), # get vars starting with "Variable"
       function(col_name){
         t = table(DF[, c('Asurion', col_name)]) 
         data.frame(prop.table(t, 1), CounT = c(t))
       }
)

[[1]]
  Asurion Variable_1 Freq CounT
1       N          a 0.50     1
2       Y          a 0.75     3
3       N          b 0.50     1
4       Y          b 0.25     1

[[2]]
  Asurion Variable_2 Freq CounT
1       N          c  0.5     1
2       Y          c  0.5     2
3       N          d  0.5     1
4       Y          d  0.5     2

[[3]]
  Asurion Variable_3 Freq CounT
1       N          f 0.50     1
2       Y          f 0.75     3
3       N          g 0.50     1
4       Y          g 0.25     1
```

Data per @Zhiqiang Wang:

```
DF<-data.frame(contract_ID = 1:6, 
               Asurion = c("Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y"), 
               Variable_1 = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b","a"), 
               Variable_2 = c("c", "d", "c", "d", "c", "d"), 
               Variable_3 = c("f", "g", "g", "f", "f", "f"))
```